# Setting Url to a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to set an image to a `WebView` for my app.

I am using the below code to set the image to my `WebView`,

```
  String imageUrl =  " file:///android_res/drawable/dinner_menu.png";
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourwebview);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   wv.loadUrl(imageUrl);
```

This works fine for **Android 2.2 and higher**.

But if I try to run the code in **2.1 or lower**, it shows an error as,

The requested file was not found `/android_res/drawable/dinner_menu.png`.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try putting your image in your assets folder, and load it using:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/dinner_menu.png");
setContentView(webView);
```

It should work on earlier versions of Android, but you'll need to manually manage using different versions of your image for different screen sizes / densities.