# Android google map from a fragment like a browser

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary, webview

for my GoogleMaps API to run, the user needs to install Google Services.

I don't want my user to feel obligated to do that. I wonder if it is possible for me to create a fragment or something like a WebView and access Google Maps through browser (frame in my app) and the user doesnt need to install google services.

Any advice, tutorial or example would be very appreciated. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use WebView element and simply use this:

```
WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
browser.loadUrl("maps.google.com");
```

Or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382441/setting-url-to-a-webview)